Best call to actions for a course provider website
I work for a technology course provider in Australia. We provide technology courses for university researchers and staff.
On our schedule webpage, We have three main call to actions for each course: "Enrol now", "Join waitlist" and "Contact your local DRA".

DRA stands for digital research analyst and refers to a dedicated training person based in each university. By clicking on the "Contact your local DRA" button, users will be directed to the DRA webpage where they can find the local DRA and their email address and contact them.

Here are my questions:
1- Is there a better way to facilitate contacting DRAs? Considering that we don't want to share course registration links publicly so each DRA can prioritise participants from her university?
2- Would it be better to have a shorter copy with an acronym such as "Contact your local DRA" or a longer copy without an acronym such as "Contact your local Digital Research Analyst" or a generic copy without an acronym such as "Contact your local training officer"? Does the existence of an unknown acronym reduce the possibility of clicking on that button?
I am open to suggestions for other improvements as well.

Given the possibility that the question may be closed for using this platform to offer a service, I recommend using screenshots instead of URLs.

@Danielillo Thank you for your comment. In fact, I am not offering a service. Our services are for member universities only and not open to the public.

It's always better to show screenshots to avoid any doubt, and you don't force the potential responder to click on a link.

@Danielillo Done

Welcome to the site!
I think the copy (on buttons) is important - it will either keep me going (clicking) or it will stop me. For more, read about "information scent" on NN/g. Seeing the designs you shared, I'd think about these questions:

Avoid abbreviations such as "DRA" (unless you have a closed target user group which you definitely know they know the abbreviation).

I'm wondering about the "local" part - does that mean users are signed in so that you know their university? Is there anything else on the website which is not local - why do you feel you need to emphasize that this is a local person?

Can you display the trainer name directly? As education is heavily influenced by the relationships, a name can either trigger me to join or make me decide to stay away. An early information without me needing to go to another webpage is beneficial, I think.

Depending on what other content (that is relevant to this task) is available on the trainer's page, it might also be good to turn the navigation to the trainer's webpage into a popover with links to biography and email. In this way, the user can stay on the course list.


With all this, I might (knowing only a fraction of your project now) end up with recommending "Contact Dr. Hamideh Iraj" on the button, and either directly starting email, or opening a popover with links to biography and email.

Thanks for your detailed answer. Regarding local, I am based at the University of Adelaide so I am the local DRA for University of Adelaide people. The local DRA for University of South Australia is another person.

The DRA name cannot be on the button copy because users need to contact their local DRA anyway. If someone from University of Adelaide wants to attend University of NSW courses, that person needs to contact the University of Adelaide DRA. Then the University of Adelaide DRA contacts the University of NSW DRA to see if they have free seats for that course.

@Hamideh I wouldn't bother users with the details of who needs to contact whom. Put the name of the DRA which whom the user has to negotiate on the button.
